# If/else statement in Python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am very new to programming and Python. To get started I'm working on a little game that will ask the user for some input and then do "something" with it. **My problem is I've seem to account for if the user types in an int lower or high than my parameters BUT i can't seem to find a way to re-prompt the user if they type in anything but an int.**

With my limited knowledge *I thought that when using an if/elif/else statement if you didn't define what the if/elif is looking for than the else statement was there for everything else that you didn't account for?*

Looking for some more insight on how to master this fundamental concept

Thank you in advance!

```
prompt = True
 while prompt == True:
 user_input = input("Please give me a number that is greater than 0 but less than 10 \n >")
if  user_input > 0 and user_input <= 10:
    print("Good job " + str(user_input)  +  " is a great number")
    break

elif (user_input  > 10):
    print("Hey dummy " + str(user_input) + " is greater than 10")

elif (user_input  <= 0):
    print("Hey dummy " + str(user_input) + " is less than 0")

else:
    print("I have no idea what you typed, try again!")
```

Comment: I tried your code and got `IndentationError: unexpected indent`.

Comment: To handle input values properly, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers

Comment: Are you actually using python 3? `input()` always returns a `str`, so the way your code is written and your question make me wonder if you are accidentally running it with python 2.x

Comment: I think your issue here is due to not converting the user's (string) input into an int before comparing.

Comment: exhaustive answers to the same problem:[asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
a = -1 
while a < 0 or a > 10:
    try:
        a = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 10: "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

This will only allow the user to enter an `int` from `0` to `10`, this will also remove the need to print those messages if the number is outside of this range, if you would like to keep those messages I could make adjustments and show you how to handle that as well